# What does it mean when FindNextPrinterChangeNotification returns null for ppPrinterNotifyInfo?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using the FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification/FindNextPrinterChangeNotification methods to monitor a printer using P/Invoke from C#.

I have thoroughly read the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on this functions.

Occasionally one of my calls to FindNextPrinterChangeNotification results in a non-zero (success) return value but the ppPrinterNotifyInfo pointer is null. I can't find this behavior documented anywhere, so I'm not sure what this indicates. I can generally reproduce the issue by sending 20 or 30 prints in quick succession on my machine.

I know the handle I'm receiving from FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification is valid because other calls (both before and after the call with the null pointer) using the same handle  succeed returning notification data as expected.

Here's the definition I'm using:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "FindNextPrinterChangeNotification", SetLastError = true,
            CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int FindNextPrinterChangeNotification([In] IntPtr hChangeObject,
                                                           [Out] out Int32 pdwChange,
                                                           [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] PrinterNotifyOptions pPrinterNotifyOptions,
                                                           [Out] out IntPtr lppPrinterNotifyInfo);
```

So what's causing the null ppPrinterNotifyInfo, is this behavior documented anywhere that I'm missing, and what does it mean?

Can I safely ignore the cases where it is null and continue receiving notifications from the same handle? Does it mean I'm missing any notifications?

Comment: It is very odd that you never mentioned "and I made sure to pinvoke WaitForSingleObject on the handle before calling the function".  Required.

Comment: After calling FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification we wait for the handle to be signaled by creating a SafeWaitHandle from it and passing that into an AutoResetEvent and using WaitHandle.WaitAny() to wait for the handle to be signaled. We then confirm that it was the notification handle that was signaled before passing it in to FindNextPrinterChangeNotification.